# How to destroy all the components in sencha touch application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

am using Senchatouch for my mobile application and am want destroy all my components of the application and refresh the application

Answer (score 1):

You can reload application using below code so every component will destroy

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer not to reload the whole app.

You might want to create a base container and fill this with all your items.
At the point you want to destroy all components, simply destroy that container

```
var mainContainer = Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'container', itemId: 'mainContainer'});
mainContainer.add([allOtherItems]);
...
Ext.Viewport.down('.container[itemId=mainContainer]').destroy();
```

I would prefer to keep that mainContainer available at all time. So

```
MyApp.MainContainer = Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'container', itemId: 'mainContainer'});
```

Keeps it easier to add items over time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove everything from the viewport, you can simply do that like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.removeAll();
```

After this, if you have login panel or main panel in your app, then you should add this like below:

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main')); // Here add the home page; either login or main page of your app
```